# Facebook login with firebase in react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native

I want to add Facebook login in the react native app(Android/IOS). I have created IOS and Android apps on Facebook developer account both apps have different App ID and different App secret. And on Firebase console I have enabled 'Facebook sign-in method' which takes only one App ID and one App secret. So which App ID and App secret should I put in the firebase console. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I Found out the answer. Instead of creating  2 different apps i.e IOS and Android version on the Facebook developer account create one app and then click 'add platform' option on Facebook developer account.